# Drupal Node Table and SQL Performance Question

Tags: sql, database, drupal

This question os partially a Drupal question and partially a SQL question. I have decided to implement quite a few features on my site as nodes due to the ease and flexibility of all the node related modules. Drupal stores the basic information about a nodes in the Node table. Potentially my node table is going to be huge, perhaps with millions of rows. I understand from reading the documentation that large tables can slow down queries, particularly in Joins. What i don't really understand is how to quantify that. I know that the specific query, the hardware and a number of other factors are involved, but I'm wondering all other variables being equal, is there some sort of equation of table size to query time? would a table with 100,000 rows take 10 times as long to execute a query than one with 10,000 rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The execution time of a query depends very much on the query and the structure of the database - particularly the indexes. It is entirely possible for a 10x size table to take 10x the time to search, and it's also entirely possible for a 10x size table to take exactly the same time to search.

MySQL's [explain query feature](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) is great for figuring out where your queries can be optimized to run faster.

Comment: There really is no generic answer. You will need to verify all queries on their own, especially dynamic/complicated queries like those generated by (complex) views or node_access.

Comment: Well I suppose that I'll do some benchmarking with a small number of nodes, then create a large number and see how long the same query takes (for number of different queries). I'm really just interested to see if there is any sort of generic rule, in terms of drupal number of nodes and query time.